# OBIEE: How to calculate the number of customers with 50 to 100 orders

Tags: obiee

these days I struggled with these nested aggregation, to calculate how many customers has 50 to 100 orders, in fact it is Aggregate of a conditional aggregate. So in OBIEE rpd, I create one **Level based measure**:

Count distinct order IDs BY Customer Level.

Then I try to case this in Analysis:

CASE WHEN "Orders"."Orders_count" BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN "Customer"."Customer ID" ELSE NULL END with count distinct Aggregation rule, but it seems gives me the wrong results. What I'm missing here? Can you help me?

Comment: "it seems gives me the wrong results" - you will have to be a lot more precise. This is analytics and not "guess how many finger I  am holding up".

Comment: OBIЕЕ gives me many rows of 1 and 0 for each month instead of one line with the number of unique customers. Like it returns a line check for each client, but I need the data to be aggregated in the end.